# Improving Geostatistical Analyst Wizard performance?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, performance, geostatistical-analyst

I have performed CoKriging using Geostatistical Analyst in ArcGIS 10. When I tried to export the prediction to raster, the process became so slow.

Is there a way to make the exporting faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how large of an area your interpolated surface covers, you can try setting a bigger cell size when you export the surface to a raster.  That should make the process much quicker.

Comment: My target cell size is 1 km. Is there a way to make this faster?

Comment: There may not be a way to speed up the process. Have you actually set the cell size to 1km or is that just your target? If not setting the cell size to that will make the process faster.